# Use .yml on spring config/resources files by default on Intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-initializr

I'm adding a new Project on Intellij using Spring Initialzr. So when my project is created, I have the *application* file already created. But it has the ".properties" extension and I prefer the YAML format.

Is there any way to configure Intellij to create this files using ".yml" or ".yaml" by default?

I know that I can just go and change the extension, but it's be awesome if I can configure that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the project (including the properties file with .properties extension) is created by spring initializr not intellij (more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started)).

Do you want to develop a plugin to change from the properties to yaml automatically once the project is imported in IntelliJ?

If so, you could use an alternative like this one -> [Intellij Plugin - Properties to yaml converter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8000-properties-to-yaml-converter)

Comment: I'll try the plugin.